# Erro Método Update EF Core com Firebird 2.5

Tags: c#, firebird, entity-framework-core, firebird-2.5

Ao tentar atualizar uma entidade o Firebird está me retornando esse erro "Implementation limit exceeded block size exceeds implementation restriction", simplesmente pego a entidade do banco e manda atualizar sem alterar nada na mesma, pelo que vi no link [FaqFirebird](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq299/) esse erro ocorre quando o select ultrapassa o tamanho de 64kb, porém quero inserir uma imagem no banco que é um campo Blob.

Classe que Define a tabela

```
public class Hospede : EntityBase
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Sexo { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string TelefoneResidencial { get; set; }
    public string TelefoneCelular { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public string RG { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string Passaporte { get; set; }
    public string Nacionalidade { get; set; }
    public byte[] AssinaturaDigital { get; set; }
    #region Endereço
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public string Complemento { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    public string Pais { get; set; }
    public string Cep { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public virtual ICollection<Reserva> Reserva { get; set; }
}
```

o Mapeamento da Entidade

```
public class HospedeMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Hospede>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Hospede> map)
    {
        map.ToTable("TABHOSPE");
        map.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        map.Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasColumnName("F_COD");
        map.Property(x => x.Nome)
            .HasColumnName("F_NOME");
        map.Property(x => x.Email)
            .HasColumnName("EMAIL");
        map.Property(x => x.Sexo)
            .HasColumnName("F_SEXO");
        map.Property(x => x.Telefone)
            .HasColumnName("F_FONE");
        map.Property(x => x.TelefoneResidencial)
            .HasColumnName("FONERES");
        map.Property(x => x.TelefoneCelular)
            .HasColumnName("FONECEL");
        map.Property(x => x.DataNascimento)
            .HasColumnName("F_NASCIM");
        map.Property(x => x.RG)
            .HasColumnName("F_RG");
        map.Property(x => x.CPF)
            .HasColumnName("F_CPF");
        map.Property(x => x.Passaporte)
            .HasColumnName("PASSAPORT");
        map.Property(x => x.Nacionalidade)
            .HasColumnName("NACIONALIDADE");
        map.Property(x => x.DataNascimento)
            .HasColumnName("F_NASCIM");
        map.Property(x => x.AssinaturaDigital)
            .HasColumnName("ASSINATURA_DIGITAL");
        map.Property(x => x.Endereco)
            .HasColumnName("F_ENDERECO");
        map.Property(x => x.Numero)
            .HasColumnName("NUMERO");
        map.Property(x => x.Complemento)
            .HasColumnName("COMPLEMENTO");
        map.Property(x => x.Bairro)
            .HasColumnName("F_BAIRRO");
        map.Property(x => x.Cidade)
            .HasColumnName("F_CIDADE");
        map.Property(x => x.Estado)
            .HasColumnName("F_ESTADO");
        map.Property(x => x.Pais)
            .HasColumnName("PAIS");
        map.Property(x => x.Cep)
            .HasColumnName("F_CEP");
        map.HasMany(x => x.Reserva)
            .WithOne(x => x.Hospede);
    }
}
```

Estrutura da Tabela

```
create table TABHOSPE{
   F_COD integer,
   F_NOME varchar(100),
   F_FONE varchar(20),
   F_SEXO varchar(1),
   F_NASCIM date,
   F_ENDERECO varchar(60),
   F_BAIRRO varchar(60),
   F_CIDADE varchar(60),
   F_ESTADO varchar(2),
   F_CEP varchar(9),
   F_RG varchar(15),
   F_CPF varchar(15),
   NACIONALIDADE varchar(60),
   PAIS varchar(60),
   FONERES varchar(20),
   FONECEL varchar(20),
   EMAIL varchar(80),
   PASSAPORT varchar(20),
   COMPLEMENTO varchar(30),
   NUMERO integer,
   ASSINATURA_DIGITAL Blob
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível gravar em campos blobs valores muito grande de uma vez. Como você mesmo constatou o tamanho máximo das instruções SQL no Firebird é de 64 Kb.

O que você deve fazer para contornar esse limite é quebrar o blob em várias partes menores e executar primeiro um INSERT para inserir a primeira parte, seguido de UPDATE's que concatenam as demais partes. Você deve fazer tudo em uma única transação e no final dar um COMMIT para efetivar a alteração ou ROLLBACK para desfazer.

Para concatenar campos blob você deve obrigatoriamente utilizar uma função que realize esse procedimento sem perdas ou corrupção, pois o Firebird não possui esse recurso de forma nativa. Recomendo a utilização da biblioteca **FreeAdhoc**, ela dispõe de muitas funções para manipulação completa de campos blob.

Página oficial da FreeAdhoc: http://freeadhocudf.org/index_eng.html

Página das funções para manipulação de campos blob: http://freeadhocudf.org/documentation_english/dok_eng_blob.html

*A biblioteca deve ser instalada no seu banco de dados para que possa ser utilizada diretamente nas instruções SQL.*

Comment: Eu fiz diversos testes na entidade, para tentar achar a melhor maneira para corrigir, como é um sistema legado a tabela  em si tem bastante campos, eu reduzi os campos mínimos necessários até onde o erro não acontece e estou conseguindo gravar, caso seja necessário atualizar mais campos considerarei utilizar essa sua opção ou mesmo dividir em duas entidades para fazer o CRUD no banco.

Comment: Mesmo que na sua instrução de update ou insert tenha apenas um campo blob, você terá sempre que cuidar para que o tamanho da instrução não ultrapasse os 64 Kb, e o que torna as coisas ainda mais complicadas é que você precisa gravar uma imagem, portanto, é mais seguro pegar o tamanho da imagem, dividir por 55 e arredondar pra cima.